# aws Lambda function access policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I added a permission to my Lambda function access policy using "aws lambda add-permission". I can get the policy back with "aws lambda get-policy", but where can I see the policy in the AWS Management Console?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I couldn't find it in the console, either.

[Using Resource-Based Policies for AWS Lambda (Lambda Function Policies)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html) says:

> The console doesn't support directly modifying permissions in a function policy. You must use either the AWS CLI or the AWS SDKs.

Comment: Same page says "You can use the console to view your function policy by choosing the Triggers tab on your function's details page and then choosing View function policy." But I don't see this tab.

Comment: The function policy is visible on the Permissions tab but as per this answer, you can't modify it from the console.

Answer (score 6):

Select the lambda function in the console, there is a key icon in the "Designer" tab. Click this icon to show the function policy.

Answer (score 0):

The interface has changed: in AWS console click on your lambda function -> Configuration -> click on Policy Statement name under 'Policy statements'-> Click Edit button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0H08.png)